# Project using a DLL cannot find the dependencies of that library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl

**Description:**

I am making a rudimentary game engine in visual studio, which aims to support a few games. As of now my solution includes a DLL project being the engine itself, and a "Game0" project which is a windows application.

The engine uses SDL, an external library, and compiles normally. The SDL C++ and dll files are included in the engine project. The engine project is also set as a dependency of the Game0 Project.

The Game0 project only contains a main.cpp, that creates the only exposed class in the engine, called "BreezeAPI" and runs a function (code bellow). This class doesn't directly include SDL.h, and only includes other internal engine classes that use it. Both projects also use the same runtime library.

The Game0 project's only file:

```
#include "BreezeAPI.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    BreezeAPI breezeAPI("settings.ini", "Test Title");
    breezeAPI.Run();

    return 0;
}
```

The exposed class in the engine, using other internal engine files, which in turn use SDL.h. It is the Game0 project calls:

```
#include "SettingsResolver.h"
#include "MySDLWindow.h"
#include "GameCore.h"
#include "Export.h"

class BREEZEENGINE_API  BreezeAPI
{
public:
    BreezeAPI(const std::string& settingsFile, const char* title);
    void Run();

private:
    std::unique_ptr<SettingsResolver> settings;
    std::unique_ptr<MySDLWindow> window;
    std::unique_ptr<GameCore> game;
};
```

**Problem:**

The Game0 project recognizes the BreezeAPI class normally, but it won't compile. The errors I get are about not being able to open the SDL.h source files that the internal engine classes use.

I obviously don't want to link the Game0 project with the SDL libraries as it should be something only required by the engine. Since the engine, which the game is supposed to use, compiles with the SDL dependencies, why am I only getting errors on the Game0 project that these dependencies are missing, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `#include "BreezeAPI.h"` does this file from the `Game0` project make use of any SDL header files either directly or indirectly?

Comment: `BreezeAPI.h` make sure that none of the 4 includes in this header include `SDL.h`

Comment: `class BREEZEENGINE_API  BreezeAPI { ... };` does not currently look like it needs to include any header at all. Forward declarations would work for the current contents if  you provided a destructor and implemented it in the cpp file.

Comment: Thanks, I realized what I had to do - removed the includes and just declared the classes in the header, added the includes in the cpp instead, along with the destructor. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From error it seems included headers are using SDL.h and trying to find it. Try adding header paths of SDK to engine project (Additional include directory).